# How to select few fields from a Entity in Spring Boot using Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a use case where I want to display the contents of an entity but hide certain fields. My entity is as follows -

Entity

```
public class StudentDetail {

@Id
private Long ID;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;

@JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy", timezone="IST")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateOfBirth;
}
```

It has many other properties as well which I am not showing here.

Repository -

```
@Repository
public interface StudentDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentDetail, Integer> {
@Query("select d from StudentDetail d where month(d.dateOfBirth) = ?1 ")
    List<StudentDetail> getStudentListBasedOnDateOfBirth(int month);

}
```

Service class -

```
public List<StudentDetail> getStudentBirthdayDetails(int month) {
        List<StudentDetail> StudentDetail = StudentDetailsRepository.getStudentListBasedOnDateOfBirth(month);
        return StudentDetail;
    }
```

And there is a controller class which calls the Service class with a `month` parameter to filter the data set.

What I want to do is modify the query in Repository class and include only the `firstname`, `middleName` and `lastName` property. The Repository class should hide the `dateOfBirth` field. I realise that the following query will return the filtered items -

```
select d.firstName, d.middleName, d.lastName from StudentDetail d where month(d.dateOfBirth) = ?1
```

However, the return type of the `Repository` class is of Entity Type  StudentDetail . Selecting only few fields from it will result in error. So, I want to know what changes should I make in the `repo`/`service` and `controller` class (assuming only return types of the classes will change ) ?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called *projection*, and Spring offers you two ways to accomplish it.
Keep in mind this exists in JPA terms, not only in Spring.

Taking your `Repository` as a starting point

```
@Repository
public interface StudentDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentDetail, Integer> {
   ...
}
```

we can use

1. `interface`-based projection
   simply create an interface which represents the result you want to have

---

```
public interface StudentDetailProjection {
   String getFirstName();
   String getMiddleName();
   String getLastName();
}
```

and add a method to your `Repository`

```
@Repository
public interface StudentDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentDetail, Integer> {
   StudentDetailProjection get...(...);
}
```

Spring will subclass that interface automatically and it will ask JPA to execute a query which will extract only the specified fields.

2. `class`-based projection
   works in almost the same way as interface-based projection, but no proxying and sub-classing is necessary, as you're offering Spring a concrete class.

---

```
public class StudentDetailProjection {
   private final String getFirstName;
   private final String getMiddleName;
   private final String getLastName;

   public StudentDetailProjection(
      final String getFirstName,
      final String getMiddleName,
      final String getLastName,
   ) {...}

   // Getters
}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) goes more in depth.

Also, a must read is [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) blog post by Vlad Mihalcea, the master of JPA.

---

The method might look, approximately, like

```
@Query("select new your.package.StudentDetailProjection(d.firstName, d.middleName, d.lastName) from StudentDetail d where month(d.dateOfBirth) = ?1")
List<StudentDetailProjection> getStudentListBasedOnDateOfBirth(final int month);
```

This will go along the concrete `class` option (2), because a constructor is required.

Comment: So the interface contains only those getters which I want in the output JSON ? Also, could you explain the repository code change. What should the method contain ?

Comment: @BoudhayanDev it's all explained in the documentation, with examples, explanations and everything. Read it, and try something.

Comment: @JBNizet I added the example anyway. There are multiple ways to accomplish this, and Boudhayan Dev can read everything detailed in the  Vlad Mihalcea blog post.

Comment: @JBNizet If someone has taken the effort to write an answer and something is not clear, then I don't think I need to refer the doc. Instead it would be easier if the OP responds

Comment: @BoudhayanDev I updated the answer. Look at the bottom. That is called Constructor Expression. Still, look at the blog post I linked.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LppEdd. Very helpful. So the interface will be the return type for all the classes related to this.

Comment: @BoudhayanDev you can create multiple projections, each one mapping to different portions of your main Entity StudentDetail. Yes, the projection interface is the return type.

Comment: YEs @LppEdd got it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, wouldnt the constructor expression end up persisting the new class in DB ?

Comment: @BoudhayanDev absolutely **not**. The "new" part in the Query annotation is just to tell JPA it has to instantiate the class passing those values to the constructor. The projection **isn't** an Entity.